# Get value of Select DOM Element in ngb-tabset in Angular Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following DOM element inside a *ngFor loop (with index set to idx):

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of myArray let idx=index">
    <select [id]="'myID' + idx"></select>
</div>
```

In my component, I need to get the element's value and tried this:

```
export class HelloComponent{
    constructor() {}

    ngAfterViewInit(){
       console.log((<HTMLSelectElement>document.querySelector('#myID0')).value);
    }
}
```

It throws the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

When I do `console.log(document.querySelector('#myID0'))` I get the element printed. For some reason, I can't get the value...

**UPDATE**

I was missing the fact that my select is inside a [`ngb-tabset`](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabset/examples)

You can see the reproduction of the issue [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ybs3x). The full HTML code is:

```
<ngb-tabset>
  <ngb-tab>
      <ng-template ngbTabTitle="">Tab</ng-template>
        <div class="row" *ngFor="let item of myArray let idx=index">
          <select [id]="'myID' + idx">
            <option>Hello</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      <ng-template ngbTabContent=""></ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

Comment: `select([id]='"myID" + idx')` is not a dom element, it is a function call.

Comment: Well... it's in PUG: https://pughtml.com/

Comment: It's maybe clearer now

Comment: Not sure if typscript will yell at you but have you tried just `document.querySelector('#myID0').value`

Comment: Yes, tried it and same issue...

Comment: `console.log(document.querySelector('#myID0').value)` returns an error? `console.log(document.querySelector('#myID0'))` again and look at properties

Comment: How is `myArray` being populated?

Comment: I have updated my question... the problem is in fact a new element I wasn't aware of.

Comment: In the html there it looks like the select is *not* inside an ng-template?

Comment: In the stackblitz you posted `document.querySelector('#myID0')` is `null` - I think because at the time of `ngAfterViewInit` the property bindings in the template have not been calculated yet and so your select does not have the id.

Answer (score 1):

When working with Angular I would look to avoid accessing the DOM in such ways. You should look at implementing viewchildren. This should give you all the information you need about the element. Sorry answer has drastically changed since you made the stackblitz

```
public @ViewChildren('idx')public domElement: QueryList<any>; // be sure to import.

<select #idx> // in HTML
```

@ViewChildren can be used to return an array of the tagged elements. Which would be done like so. This will return you an array of the `*ngFor` elements.

You could then set up something simple to find the correct element.

```
const test = this.domElements.find(element => element.yourvalue === whatYouExpect);
```

Comment: `ViewChildren` takes a name of a reference variable not an id. Also the `ViewChild` attribute will be executed with the initial value of `this.requiredElement` - I don't think the idea here will work.

Comment: viewchild didnt like this.requiredElement anyway haha stackblitz helped test what I was getting at. ViewChildren can pick up #id :)

Answer (score 0):

Give your select elements a template reference variable, and use `ViewChildren` to obtain a `QueryList` in your component.

```html
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of myArray let idx=index">
    <select [id]="'myID' + idx" #selectElements></select>
</div>
```

```js
@ViewChildren('selectElements', { read: ElementRef })
selectElements: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

See https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

Comment: I have updated my question, will that solve the problem?